# Can not insert into set of classes

Tags: c++, class, set

I need. to make a set of **Rational** classes. I've overloaded < operator to make this work. But somehow values inserted only if the test passes (which is not behaviour that I want). I want to have default behaviour of set. Here is the code:

```
class Rational {
public:
    Rational() {
            numerator = 0;
            denominator = 1;
    }

    Rational(int numerator, int denominator) {
        int greatestCommonDivisor = gcd(numerator, denominator);
        this->numerator = numerator / greatestCommonDivisor;
        this->denominator = denominator / greatestCommonDivisor;
    }

    int Numerator() const {
            return numerator;
    }

    int Denominator() const {
            return denominator;
    }

    bool operator<(const Rational& rhs) const {
        return (numerator / denominator) < (rhs.Numerator() / rhs.Denominator());
    }

private:
    int numerator;
    int denominator;

    int gcd(int a, int b) {
        if (a == 0) {
            return b;
        }
        return gcd(b % a, a);
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, Rational& r);
};
```

It should pass this test:

```
int main() {
     {
         set<Rational> rs = {{1, 2}, {1, 25}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
         if (rs.size() != 3) {
            cout << "Wrong amount of items in the set" << endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

But instead **rs** now contains only *{1, 2}*.

Thank you for your help.

I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: `Rational() {
            numerator = 0;
            denominator = 1;
    }` --> better (use initialization): `Rational() : numerator(0), denominator(1) { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `numerator` and `denominator` are both of type `int`.

```
int numerator;
int denominator;
```

Then your comparator is

```
bool operator<(const Rational& rhs) const {
    return (numerator / denominator) < (rhs.Numerator() / rhs.Denominator());
}
```

Since this is doing integer division, the expression `numerator / denominator` evaluates to `0` for every single pair in this initializer list

```
{{1, 2}, {1, 25}, {3, 4}, {3, 4}, {1, 2}};
```

To fix this you'd have to switch to floating point division

```
bool operator<(const Rational& rhs) const {
    return (static_cast<double>(numerator) / static_cast<double>(denominator)) < (static_cast<double>(rhs.Numerator()) / static_cast<double>(rhs.Denominator()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this operator

```
bool operator<(const Rational& rhs) const {
    return (numerator / denominator) < (rhs.Numerator() / rhs.Denominator());
}
```

there is used the integer arithmetic.

Ay least write it this way to use the arithmetic with float numbers

```
bool operator<(const Rational& rhs) const {
    return (static_cast<double>( numerator ) / denominator) < ( static_cast<double>( rhs.Numerator() ) / rhs.Denominator());
}
```